# jQuery - Dynamically Turn List Items into jQuery Toggles

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I would like to automatically turn list items into jQuery toggles for elements in a page.

For example, here is some sample page code:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="books">Books</li>
            <li class="cars">Cars</li>
            <li class="sausages">Sausages</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="elements">
        <div class="books">This layer displays a range of books</div>
        <div class="cars">This layer displays a range of cars</div>
        <div class="sausages">This layer displays a range of sausages</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, each menu list item and each element DIV, share the same class name.

What I would like to accomplish, with jQuery, is turning each menu list item automatically into a toggle, which can then toggles its corrosponding DIV in the elements section.

So it basically needs to read the menu items, then see if that menu item has a corrosponding element layer, and if so, turn it into a toggle which can toggle the layer.

It needs to be dynamic, because menu items and element layers might be added and removed regularly and it could eventually incorporate dozens of layers.

If this is possible, please demonstrate with a jsFiddle.

Thanks!

EDIT: I know how to use jQuery to hide and show specific elements on a page, where you hard code the element name into the code, however, I have no idea how to make it dynamic.  I tried googling for at least 2 hours prior to posting here.

Comment: Doesn't work like that. You do the work, and then if there is a problem you encounter, ask for help.

Comment: Please know that we are not in the business of doing other peoples work for them. [You are going to have to show that you at least attempted to solve this yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172936)

Comment: it sounds to me like you already have a pretty good idea of what you think it should do.  Try coding it up and seeing what you get, or instead of asking us to code it for you, ask for generalized ideas around your approach and if anyone can think of a better way before you waste hours coding. We want to help you learn to fish.

Comment: I have a grasp of what I need to do, yes, however, I have no idea how to accomplish it, hence why I posted here.  I spent a couple of hours of googling this before-hand, and just got the point where I was spinning my wheels (possibly because I do not know the correct terminology), so this is why I asked here.  I know how to use jQuery to hide and show SPECIFIC elements, where you hard-code the name of the element into the code, but I have no idea how I would do it dynamically.

Comment: you can simply use a variable as a selector... `var selectedClass = $(this).attr('class'); $("."+selectedClass).html(); `

Comment: Simply saying that you searched on Google is not enough... If you say you know how to do it hard coded then show us your code.  Posting **some** attempt would show that you put some effort into trying to solve this by yourself before posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The commenters above are correct that you should put more effort into your post. Beside the fact that SO is not a "[do my homework for me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128572#128572)" site, your description is difficult for me to understand. Some code--even pseudo code--would help.*

I do understand, however, that sometimes we don't even know what we don't know, and that makes our questions very hard to communicate. So while I am having a hard time understanding what you want, if I read it correctly something like this should work:

**HMTL**

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="books">Books</li>
            <li class="cars">Cars</li>
            <li class="sausages">Sausages</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="elements">
        <div class="books">This layer displays a range of books</div>
        <div class="cars">This layer displays a range of cars</div>
        <div class="sausages">This layer displays a range of sausages</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#menu ul li').on('click', function () {
    var $matchingDIV = $('#elements div.' + $(this).attr('class'));

    $matchingDIV.toggle(!$matchingDIV.is(':visible'));
});​
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/dkxqG/)

Where it will fall down is if you add more than one class name to your LI elements. Also, I didn't know if you wanted elements to start out showing, or whether only one at a time should show, etc. Hopefully you can take this and run with it, but if you have questions on it, do ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me this.  I never, ever would have been able to arrive at that myself.